# Why does static_cast gives different memory locations for same object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-address, static-cast

My code

```
class Parent { int a; };
class Child { int b; };
struct GrandChild : public Parent, public Child { int a, b, c; };

int main() {
    GrandChild GC;
    std::cout << "GrandChild's address is at : " <<&GC<<endl;
    std::cout << "Child's address is at : " <<static_cast<Child*>(&GC)<<endl;
    std::cout << "Parent's address is at : " <<static_cast<Parent*>(&GC)<<endl;

}
```

output:

```
GrandChild's address is at : 0077F6F8
Child's address is at : 0077F6FC
Parent's address is at : 0077F6F8
```

Why does after static_cast the memory locations have inconsistencies like above?

Comment: Interesting… learned something new today, thanks for the awesome question!

Comment: As an aside, these type names are extremely misleading!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sry,I didn't get how :(

Comment: @InQusitive: It's common to call base classes "parent" and derived classes "child". Since you've reused the terms to represent biological familial relationships (and inaccurately, at that), with an example in which the type "child" does _not_ derive from the type "parent", that's confusing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`GrandChild` derives from both `Parent` and `Child`.  As such, a `GrandChild` object in memory consists of both a `Parent` object and a `Child` object within its memory.

`&GC` by itself returns the memory address of the `GrandChild` object as a whole

`static_cast<Parent*>(&GC)` returns the starting address of the `Parent` portion inside the `GrandChild` object.

`static_cast<Child*>(&GC)` returns the starting address of the `Child` portion inside the `GrandChild` object.

In your case, `Grandchild` derives from `Parent` first, so the `Parent` portion is aligned at the beginning of the `GrandChild`'s memory block.  Then the `Child` portion follows the `Parent` portion.  Here is an illustration to show that:

[image: structure]

Comment: This picture showed me where I was wrong in the comments, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`&GC` is the address of the `GrandChild` object `GC`. `static_cast<Child*>(&GC)` is the address of the `Child` *subobject* of `GC`. And `static_cast<Parent*>(&GC)` is the address of the `Parent` *subobject* of `GC`.

In your particular implementation, it appears that a `GrandChild` object starts with a `Parent` subobject and then the `Child` subobject comes after, so the `Parent` subobject's address is the same as the complete `GrandChild` object's address, but the `Child` subobject's first byte is *not* the first byte of the complete `GrandChild` object, so its address is higher. You *cannot* rely on this behaviour being portable, however; different implementations may allocate base class and member subobjects in different orders, and do not even need to be consistent between different classes.

Comment: Why is the memory start is similar for `Parent` and `GrandChild` in this example? Don't they ought to be aligned in ascending memory order? And how do they share the same memory chunk?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy A `GrandChild` object contains within itself both a `Parent` object and a `Child` object. It happens that on the OP's compiler, the `Parent` object is allocated at the very beginning of the `GrandChild` object. They share a memory chunk because the `Parent` object is genuinely *part of* the `GrandChild` object.

Comment: I mean, in my opinion the classes in memory should be aligned as this: `Base1, Base2, Base 3, ...` with their own data as it is described [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/12/17/dumping-a-c-objects-memory-layout-with-clang). So, according to clang the `Parent::a` should be the start of current object layout, and the `GrandChild::a` should be the start of `GrandChild` object's memory without any intersection.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy, but `GrandChild::a` happens, with the OP's compiler, to be allocated after the `Parent` subobject of the `GrandChild` object. A pointer to a `GrandChild` object therefore doesn't point to the member `a`. The standard does not say it has to.

Comment: Of course standard does not regulate this but compiler should do something, in logical way, is not it? If not, how the hell the compiler authors did implement this? I just can't understand how two classes may intersect memory of each other. I understand that memory does not exactly start from the members, but in this example, it should be, because we have no any virtual table or anything that may prevent this. What else should class's memory start from if not the it's data section? :)

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: You seem to be not understanding that the base class object is literally part of the derived class object. The `Parent` sub-object (including its `a` member) is just as much a part of the data of the `GrandChild` object as are the 3 members (`a`, `b` and `c`) declared in the class definition. You seem to be expecting the address of the `GrandChild` object to be not at the beginning of the `GrandChild` object (which would coincide with the address of the `Parent` sub-object), but instead somewhere in the middle (where the members declared in the `GrandChild` class are located).

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: Oh, and there's no objects intersecting each-other's memory. The `GrandChild` object is laid out something like `Parent` sub-object first, then  `Child` sub-object, then members `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, it is predictable even if it is implementation defined (but implementers are allowed to choose straight solutions for simple cases :-) )

Here is the memory representation of your object (deduced from the addresses, not from the standard !):

```
Parent::a (int = 4 bytes)
Child::b (int = 4 bytes)
GrandChild::a
GrandChild::b
GrandChild::c
```

This is because of your declaration : `GrandChild` inherits first from `Parent`, next from `Child`. With that representation, it makes sense for `Parent`'s address to be the same as `GrandChild`'s one, and for `Child`'address to be 4 bigger.

Also note that `GrandChild::a` is **not** `Parent::a`...

Comment: Why is `Parent`'s address is same as `GrandChild`'s one, I don't understand. Please, clarify

Comment: @VictorPolevoy - it *can* be the same, but it doesn't *have to* be. Note that `Parent::a` *also* has the same address as both `Parent` and `GrandChild`.  :-) Generally, objects of different types are *allowed* to have the same address, because they can't be confused with each other anyway. Two objects of **the same type** must have different addresses.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: Because that's the address at which the 4-byte `Parent` sub-object starts, _and_ the address at which the entire n-byte `GrandChild` object starts. The only place this gets "funny" is that the address at which the 4-byte `Child` sub-object starts is different.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it depends on the sequence in which the GrandChild inherits from Parent and Child.

With the following sequence I got

```
struct GrandChild : public Parent, public Child { int a, b, c; };
```

Output 1: GrandChilds's address is same as Parent's address

```
GrandChild's address is at : 0x22fecc
Child's address is at : 0x22fed0
Parent's address is at : 0x22fecc
```

On changing the sequence in which GrandChild inherits from Child and Parent to

```
struct GrandChild :  public Child , public Parent { int a, b, c; };
```

Output 2: GrandChilds's address is same as Child's address

```
GrandChild's address is at : 0x22fecc
Child's address is at : 0x22fecc
Parent's address is at : 0x22fed0
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here have perfectly done the job, but let me bother anyhow.

Firstly, Parent is not a parent and Child is not a child... of Parent; as it didn't inherit from Parent. Both Parent and Child are inheritance of GrandParent, which is not... a grand parent!

Secondly to answer your question, it effects you observe are not really inconsistencies, but how C++ implements polymorphism. ( I DONT THINK THE OTHER ANSWERS MADE THIS CLEAR).

PolyMorphism (poly = many, morphism = morphing into), is an object oriented programming concept that allows one object to be able to morph into many different objects at runtime. This allows the object to behave differently. For example, it can be a dog now, a cat next and a ghost later.

How polymorphism is implemented in most object oriented languages, C++, Java, etc is by means of pointer arithmetic( incrementation ) and inheritance. It would be cool if a std::string could morph into a std::vector, but because they dont share inheritance it is syntacally impossible.

However in case of your Parent class, it can morph into a GrandParent, or any other derived class. Similarly, a GrandParent can morph into a Parent or a Child.

ANOTHER NAME FOR POLYMORPHISM IS POLYMORPHIC CONVERSION!!!

It is important to understand, based on your  question, that polymorphism is a type of C++ conversion. C++ conversions are designed to be accurate and lossless. For example, you can convert an int to a char and back. The INTEGRITY of the data is MAINTAINED! Similarly, if I am converting from a GrandParent to a Child( which is what a static_cast does); it is best to set the pointer of the object to the address of Child. If we convert to child and continue reading from GrandParent, then we would be reading WRONG DATA. In your case where you inherited from Parent first, we would end up read the a and b value stored in Parent.

To make matters worse and more obvious that this kind of conversion would be wrong. If we convert to Child, and child has a special function called getString for example, if we called this function from the starting address of GrandChild, BOOM! We surely get a runtime crash!

Well hope you enjoyed this video and learnt something. If you want more free videos remember to like and subscribe. Thank you.